# χάριτος (charitos)

Tags: greek

What is the literal definition of χάριτος (charitos)?

I have read some claim that this means "to give grace" while others claim it means "charming" "Loving" or "highly favored"

Who is correct, and why?

**John 1:14**

> "And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as  of the only Son from the Father, full of **grace** and truth".  [grace/charitos]. ESV My emphasis.

New Living Translation does not have "grace" in John 1:14 but has "He was full of unfailing  love".

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site, Patrick. Just to point out that on here a Bible text must form the basis of any question. This is not a site for discussing topics. If you could quote a Bible verse where this Greek word appears and explain the sources where you have seen different translations, then we could make a start.

Comment: @Patrick Shurina Welcome to BH. In trying to improve  your question forgive me if I have taken it in a direction that is not to your suiting. And delete what I have put.

Answer (score 2):

The pertinent word in John 1:14 is χάρις/χάριτος (charis/charitos) occurs 157 times in the NT, and according the BDAG means:

> 1. **a winning quality or attractiveness that invites a favorable reaction, *graciousness, attractiveness, charm, welcomeness***, eg,
>    Luke 4:22, Col 4:6
> 2. **a beneficent disposition toward someone, *favor, grace, gracious, care/help, goodwill*** (almost a technical term in the
>    reciprocity-oriented world dominated by Hellenic influences as well as
>    by the semitic sense expressed in the term חסד. Of a different order
>    and spirit is the subset of reciprocity known as Roman patronage, in
>    which superiority of the donor over the client is clearly maintained.)
>
> - (a) active: that which one grants to another, the action of one who volunteers to do something not otherwise obligatory, Luke 2:40, Acts
>   11:2, 14:26, 14:40, especially of the beneficent intention of God and
>   of Christ who give undeserved gift to people Rom 3:24, 5:15a, 20f,
>   6:1, 11:5, 6, Gal 1:15, Eph 1:6, 2:5, 7, 8; 2 Thess 1:12, 2:16, 1:9; 2
>   Tim 1:9, Tit 2:11, Heb 2:9, 4:16, Rom 4:4, 16, etc
> - (b) passive: that which one experiences from another, 3 John 4, Acts 2:47, Luke 1:30, Acts 7:46, Luke 2:52, Acts 4:33, 7:10, etc.
> - (c) In Christian epistolatory literature from the time of Paul χάρις is found with the sense (divine) favor in fixed formulas at the
>   beginning and end of letters Rom 1:7, 1 Cor 1:3, 2 Cor 1:2, Gal 1:3,
>   Eph 1:2, Phil 1:2, Col 1:2, Rev 1:2, etc.
>
> 3. **practical application of goodwill, *(a sign of) favor, gracious deed/gift, benefaction***
>
> - (a) on the part of humans Acts 24:27, 25:3, 9; 2 Cor 1:15; 1 Cor 16:3; 2 Cor 8:4, 6, 19; Eph 4:29
> - (b) on the part of God and Christ; the context will show whether the emphasis is upon the *possession of divine favor* as a source of
>   blessing for the believer, or upon a *store of favor* (ie, standing in
>   God's favor) that is brought about, or a *gracious deed* wrought by
>   God in Christ, or a *gracious work* that grows from more to more, 1
>   peter 5:10, James 4:6; 1 Peter 5:5, **John 1:14**, 16, 17, Rom 5:2, 17; 1
>   Cor 1:4; 2 Cor 5:15, Acts 11:23, 6:1, Gal 1:6, 2:21, 5:4, Col 1:6,
>   etc.
>
> 4. **Exceptional effect produced by generosity, *favor***, 1 Cor 8:1, 9:14, Rom 1:5, 12:3, 15:15; 1 Cor 3:10, 15:10; 2 Cor 12:9, Gal 2:9,
>    Eph 3:2, 7, Phil 1:7, Rom 12:6, Eph 4:7; 1 Peter 4:10, etc
> 5. **response to generosity of beneficence, *thanks, gratitude*** (a fundamental component in the Graeco-Roman reciprocity system) mostly
>    of gratitude to God or Christ; χάρις in our literature as a whole, in
>    the sense of *gratitude*, refers to appropriate response to the Deity
>    for benefits conferred 2 Tim 1:3; 1 Tim 1:12, Phlm 7; Heb 12:28, Rom
>    7:25, 6:17; 2 Cor 9:15, 2:14, 8:16; 1 Cor 15:57, 10:30, Col 3:16.

This means this well-used word had a variety of meanings.  Technically, the noun χάρις is derived from the verb χαίρω (chairó) meaning "to rejoice and be glad".  However, root meanings are not always a good guide to usage.

In John 1:14, the TLV appears to be an interpretive translation.  John's meaning appears to be "grace" in the sense of Christ bestowing multiplied benefits by way of salvific gifts.  That is, Jesus is the means of unmerited eternal salvation (Acts 4:12, 1 John 5:11, 12).

Answer (score 0):

I just read this in a newsletter recently. The Greek word charistos is a derivative of the word charis, which is the New Testament word for grace. However, when the word charis is transformed into charistos, it more fully expresses the idea of one whose heart is thankful, grateful, or appreciative for various reasons. One scholar says the Greek word charistos depicts an inward awareness of having been fortunate or well-treated.  Thus, the word “thankful” — translated from charistos — projects the deep inward feeling of one who is thankful, grateful, or appreciative for what one has received or how one has been treated by others.

- From Rick Renner "Teaching you can Trust"

Comment: Welcome to BHSX and joining the group.  Thanks for your contribution and answer.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site works and why it is a little different from others.

Comment: @ Sactown Girl - Thanks for your input! However, it would be beneficial to go deeper into the original languages for more substantial research. The homilies by Mr. Renner are good exhortations and do have value in encouraging believers. Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!